# Parse XML in SQL Server (with an array)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to parse some XML in SQL Server, i've developed some code to do it but one of the data items returned come in the form of an array?

SQL So far, with example XML...

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feedback-items>
<feedback-item id="1001">
<message>The message</message>
<sentiment-score>3</sentiment-score>
<channel>SMS</channel>
<structured-fields>
<structured-field>
<name>loyalty_card_number</name>
<value>123456</value>
</structured-field>
<structured-field>
<name>given_score</name>
<value>4</value>
</structured-field>
</structured-fields>
<categories>
<category>People</category>
<category>Process</category>
<category>Product</category>
<category>Place</category>
</categories>
<insights>
<insight>
<category>People</category>
<sentiment-score>1</sentiment-score>
</insight>
</insights>
<notes>
<note>
<id>1</id>
<username>Bob</username>
<created>2012-12-11 09:00:00</created>
<content>The customer was happy</content>
</note>
</notes>
</feedback-item>
<feedback-item id="1002">
<message>The message</message>
<sentiment-score>3</sentiment-score>
<channel>SMS</channel>
<structured-fields>
<structured-field>
<name>loyalty_card_number</name>
<value>123456</value>
</structured-field>
<structured-field>
<name>given_score</name>
<value>6</value>
</structured-field>
</structured-fields>
<categories>
<category>People</category>
<category>Process</category>
<category>Product</category>
<category>Place</category>
</categories>
<insights>
<insight>
<category>People</category>
<sentiment-score>1</sentiment-score>
</insight>
</insights>
<notes>
<note>
<id>1</id>
<username>Mike</username>
<created>2012-12-12 09:00:00</created>
<content>The customer was happy</content>
</note>
</notes>
</feedback-item>
</feedback-items>
'

SELECT 
    xmlData.A.value('@id','INT') AS [FeedbackItem]
    --fields.A.value('./Name/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [Name]
    --xmlData.A.value('(./structured-fields/structured-field/Name/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [Name]
FROM @XML.nodes('feedback-items/feedback-item') xmlData(A)
        --CROSS APPLY xmlData.A.nodes('/structured-fields/structured-field') AS fields(A)
```

Desired output...

| Feedback Item | Message | Sentiment Score | Channel | Loyalty Card Number | Given Score | Username | Created | Content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | The message | 3 | SMS | 123456 | 6 | Bob | 2012-12-11 | The Customer was happy |
| 1002 | The message | 3 | SMS | 123456 | 4 | Mike | 2012-12-12 | The Customer was happy |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code

```sql
SELECT
  [Feedback Item] = fb.value('@id','int'),
  Message = fb.value('(message/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)'),
  [Sentiment Score] = fb.value('(sentiment-score/text())[1]','int'),
  Channel = fb.value('(channel/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)'),
  [Loyalty Card Number] = fb.value('(structured-fields/structured-field[name[text()="loyalty_card_number"]]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)'),
  [Given Score] = fb.value('(structured-fields/structured-field[name[text()="given_score"]]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)'),
  Username = fb.value('(notes/note/username/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)'),
  Created = fb.value('(notes/note/created/text())[1]','datetime'),
  Content = fb.value('(notes/note/content/text())[1]','nvarchar(200)')
FROM @xml.nodes('feedback-items/feedback-item') x(fb)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8adcd5cd0ec274edcbf87692ca1bb187)

Further Notes:

- The XML was truncated, I've added some more to it to get the desired result. I assume you had more.
- Note how `structured-field` is filtered on `name/text()` and then `value/text(0` is retrieved
- `notes/note` looks like it may contain multiple items, you may want to break this out separately with another `.nodes`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

Your XPath expressions were way off.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<feedback-items>
    <feedback-item id="1001">
        <message>The message</message>
        <sentiment-score>3</sentiment-score>
        <channel>SMS</channel>
        <structured-fields>
            <structured-field>
                <name>loyalty_card_number</name>
                <value>123456</value>
            </structured-field>
            <structured-field>
                <name>given_score</name>
                <value>4</value>
            </structured-field>
        </structured-fields>
        <categories>
            <category>People</category>
            <category>Process</category>
            <category>Product</category>
            <category>Place</category>
        </categories>
        <insights>
            <insight>
                <category>People</category>
                <sentiment-score>1</sentiment-score>
            </insight>
        </insights>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <id>1</id>
                <username>Bob</username>
                <created>2012-12-11 09:00:00</created>
                <content>The customer was happy</content>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </feedback-item>
    <feedback-item id="1002">
        <message>The message</message>
        <sentiment-score>3</sentiment-score>
        <channel>SMS</channel>
        <structured-fields>
            <structured-field>
                <name>loyalty_card_number</name>
                <value>123456</value>
            </structured-field>
            <structured-field>
                <name>given_score</name>
                <value>6</value>
            </structured-field>
        </structured-fields>
        <categories>
            <category>People</category>
            <category>Process</category>
            <category>Product</category>
            <category>Place</category>
        </categories>
        <insights>
            <insight>
                <category>People</category>
                <sentiment-score>1</sentiment-score>
            </insight>
        </insights>
        <notes>
            <note>
                <id>1</id>
                <username>Mike</username>
                <created>2012-12-12 09:00:00</created>
                <content>The customer was happy</content>
            </note>
        </notes>
    </feedback-item>
</feedback-items>
';

SELECT a.value('@id','INT') AS [FeedbackItem]
    , a.value('(message/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [Message]
    , a.value('(sentiment-score/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [SentimentScore]
    , a.value('(channel/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [channel]
    , a.value('(structured-fields/structured-field[name="loyalty_card_number"]/value/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [loyalty_card_number]
    , a.value('(structured-fields/structured-field[name="given_score"]/value/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [GivenScore]
    , b.value('(username/text())[1]','Varchar(50)') AS [Username]
    , b.value('(created/text())[1]','DATE') AS [created]
    , b.value('(content/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [content]
FROM @XML.nodes('/feedback-items/feedback-item') t1(a)
    CROSS APPLY t1.a.nodes('notes/note') AS t2(b);
```

**Output**

```
+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
| FeedbackItem |   Message   | SentimentScore | channel | loyalty_card_number | GivenScore | Username |  created   |        content         |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
|         1001 | The message |              3 | SMS     |              123456 |          4 | Bob      | 2012-12-11 | The customer was happy |
|         1002 | The message |              3 | SMS     |              123456 |          6 | Mike     | 2012-12-12 | The customer was happy |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
```